# Changing WinForm element from outside its class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple Windows Form with a button and textbox. I want the textbox to update with some string when the button is pressed. I know the following works:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.text = "some string";
    }
}
```

I also know, that the following will work. This gives me a bit more freedom, cause I can easily decide what I want to appear in the textbox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateText("some string");
    }

    public void updateText(string s)
    {
        textBox1.Text = s;
    }
}
```

Now, let's say that my code is getting big, and I want to keep things tidy. I want to move my code that performs updates into a different class called `Updates`. In that class I want to have a method that I can run on any `textBox` with any `string`. When I try the following, I get an error: `The name 'textBox1' does not exist in the current context`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Updates.updateText("some string");
    }
}

public class Updates
{
    public void updateText(string s)
    {
        textBox1.Text = s;
    }
}
```

I have seen more complex questions here about similar things, but I can't get their solutions to work. I think I'm missing something basic.

Additionally, I don't know how I would expand this method to accept any `textBox`, e.g.:

```
public void updateText(??? target, string s)
    {
        target.Text = s;
    }
```

What type would `target` take?

Comment: Even though the contents of the question looks okay I would rather vote to close this because it shows that you didn't even checked Microsoft's official documentation page and haven't done any research in that topic. The target type is exactly the same as the type of control you're having in your form...

Comment: I agree with @m.rogalski as this question is so extremely basic, that it can't be considered of any professional value.

Comment: I am new to programming. I checked official documentation, but I didn't understand it. Thanks for being welcoming to newbies though! Great stuff.

Comment: In Visual Studio, if you hover over a variable (`textBox1`), it will show its type (`TextBox`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function to accept TextBox like this:

```
public void updateText(TextBox target, string s)
{
    target.Text = s;
}
```

Comment: I would rather go with [`Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) type in this case as it can change text for either a `Button`, `Label` or a `TextBox`

Comment: @m.rogalski yes, you are right, Control will make the function more general. But with it will bring additional checkings if he will want to change some specific to TextBox fields

Answer (score 1):

Samvel Petrosov answer is best solution, but if you would like to have another option, there it is: set the text box modifier to `public` (or `internal`), add reference to your form in `Updates` class. Then you will be able to modify it (text box) freely.

Comment: I want to note that in this case he will need to keep an instance of `Updates` class for `Form`.